# Is it possible to sent an email with inline image using sputility?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, sputility

Does anyone knows of a way to embed an image to a powershell code sending email using SPUTILITY?

The image can be located on a shared location for that purpose (aka http://example.com/image.jpg)

Current code:

```
function sendMail
{
    asnp Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
    $web = Get-SPWeb "http://mysite"
    $sd = new-object System.collections.specialized.stringdictionary

    $sd.add("to","name@domain.com")
    $sd.add("Subject","Your new SharePoint site is ready")

    $body = "<font face='ebrima'>Hello</font>"
    $body +="<font face='ebrima'>Hi</font>"

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::SendEmail($web,$sd,$body)
}

sendMail
```

---

Thanks,
Effy.

Answer (score 1):

of course you can. you actually don't need to build you dictionary, you can use this method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms477270.aspx

```
public static bool SendEmail(
    SPWeb web,
    bool fAppendHtmlTag,
    bool fHtmlEncode,
    string to,
    string subject,
    string htmlBody,
    bool appendFooter
)
```

Image needs to be somewhere where users will be able to access it and then just write your regular HTML.